# How in delphi can i get a drawable resource ID?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

in Delphi, I add image resources to the project (via project > resources and Images), however i need for one java function to give a **resource ID in the application's package of the drawable to use**. Is it possible to retrieve a resource ID (integer) from my delphi resource file or name ?

If not, how in delphi we can add a custom resource image and retrieve it's resource ID ?

Comment: Look at the Deployment section under project settings. That page allows you to add "custom folders" that your app can use

Comment: yes i think i will need to do a custom deployment, but the problem with folders i need to add ? drawable-xxxhdpi-v4 ? drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17 ? drawable-v23 ? drawable-hdpi-v4? etc ... and after how to retrieve the resource id ? and i think i need also to make a xml file, but no idea how ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Getting a Resource ID

To retrieve the resource ID of a resource:

```
id := TAndroidHelper.GetResourceID('my_image', 'drawable');
```

If you are using an older version of Delphi you may need to use the alternate, older approach:

```
id := TAndroidHelper.Context.getResources.getIdentifier(StringToJString('my_image'), StringToJString('drawable'), TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName);
```

The shorter, more recent (and convenient) `GetResourceID` function is merely a wrapper around the earlier longer winded version.

In either case, `my_image` is the filename (without extension) of the image resource whose ID you need.

The `drawable` parameter tells the helper that it is a drawable resource ID that you are asking for (as opposed to a `string` or `layout`, for example).

### Adding Image Resources

To add a custom image resource to your project use the **Deployment** option of the **Project** menu in the IDE.

Add your file and set the `remote` path to a suitable drawable resource folder, e.g.:

```
res\drawable
res\drawable-xxhdpi

etc
```

You could put your own scaled versions of the image in each drawable folder for different resolutions.  The `remote_name` must be the same in each case.  The specific drawable folder determines the applicable device resolution.

Alternatively you could simply provide one suitably high resolution file.  You can place this in either an appropriate high-resolution folder (e.g. `drawable-xxxhdpi`) or simply in `drawable`.

Either way, Android will auto-scale the images at runtime for other device resolutions as necessary.

There are lots of Android references on the subject of drawable scaling, alternative versions for different display types etc, including [the Android documentation itself of course](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence).

Referencing your comment, there are however no XML files required for adding drawables that are straightforward images.

Additional XML *may* be necessary for other types of drawable resources, but that will very much depend on the nature of your specific needs.

### Bringing It All Together

In the screenshot below the highlighted entry is one that I have added for a PNG image resource.  The file is in my project folder so there is no local path (the first column).

[image]

The filename is `appstore.png` and I have configured the deployment to place one copy of that file in the `res\drawable' folder of the application when it is deployed (the`remote` folder).

This file will rely on auto-scaling for display on different resolutions devices.

To get the resource ID of that resource I then simply write:

```
id := TAndroidHelper.GetResourceID('appstore', 'drawable');
```

Comment: Thanks! very clear and good answer! I didn't know that we do not need to gave an xml file (ie: value.xml) to reference the .png ... i was looking so long because of this :(